# How to pxselect and get extension of selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

Hi im new in acumatica programming i have a code that gets the row of my data then i want to get the extension of that row how do i do it here is what i got so far

```
InventoryItem sel = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<CROpportunityProducts.inventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, items.InventoryID);

 var selex = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(sel);
```

how do i get that extension as you can see i tried PXCache. Get Extension but i have no luck on it. so my question is how to get the extended value of acumatica PXSELECT thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know in which context this code is executed but the following should work.

```
InventoryItemExt selExt = sel.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InventoryItem sel = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<CROpportunityProducts.inventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, items.InventoryID);
if(sel != null){
   InventoryItemExt selExt = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(sel);
}
```